# Enabling LTR in SOLRCloud (solr version8.2)

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to work with solr-cloud and I have to use learning to rank models and features for my project. But I am facing this issue of **SolrCore Initialization Failures**

**techproducts_shard1_replica_n2: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Failed to create new ManagedResource /schema/model-store of type org.apache.solr.ltr.store.rest.ManagedModelStore due to: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.ltr.model.ModelException: Model type does not exist org.apache.solr.ltr.model.LinearModel
techproducts_shard2_replica_n6: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Failed to create new ManagedResource /schema/model-store of type org.apache.solr.ltr.store.rest.ManagedModelStore due to: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.ltr.model.ModelException: Model type does not exist org.apache.solr.ltr.model.LinearModel
Please check your logs for more information**

These are the solr logs:-

```
**2019-12-04 12:44:05.760 ERROR (searcherExecutor-15-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.137.1:8983_solr x:techproducts_shard1_replica_n2 c:techproducts s:shard1 r:core_node5) [c:techproducts s:shard1 r:core_node5 x:techproducts_shard1_replica_n2] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.initComponents(SearchHandler.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.getComponents(SearchHandler.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2578)
    at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.lambda$getSearcher$18(SolrCore.java:2344)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-12-04 12:44:05.760 ERROR (searcherExecutor-14-thread-1-processing-n:192.168.137.1:8983_solr x:techproducts_shard2_replica_n6 c:techproducts s:shard2 r:core_node8) [c:techproducts s:shard2 r:core_node8 x:techproducts_shard2_replica_n6] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.initComponents(SearchHandler.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.getComponents(SearchHandler.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2578)
    at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.lambda$getSearcher$18(SolrCore.java:2344)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the compatibility of Solr version and zookeeper....
For **Solr 8.2.0** use **zookepeer 3.5.6**